# Possible to return an object into a completion block?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, afnetworking

I work with Core data and I want to call a function for returning an object. This object is completed in this function with AFNetworking into a completion block. I want to know if it's possible to return this object into this completion block... for use it later. Failed code here, because newMember in completion block is not allowed and not working.

This error appears :
`Incompatible block pointer types sending 'Member *(^)(NSURLRequest...'`

```
+(Member *)returnMemberModelWithId:(NSString *)myid withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{
    __block NSMutableArray *dicoNe =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    __block Member *newMember = [NSEntityDescription
                         insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Member"
                         inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSString *s= @".json";
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", myid, s];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://epnet.fr/"]];

    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
    [httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFFormURLParameterEncoding];
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"members/%@", str];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:path parameters:nil];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *innerRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id reponseJSON) {
        dicoNe = reponseJSON;

        NSNumber *v = [dicoNe valueForKey:@"id"];
        newMember.idMember = v; //And others assignments ..

        return newMember;  // It's not working
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *innerRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id reponseJSON) {
        NSLog(@"Fail %@", reponseJSON);
    }];
    [operation start];

    return newMember; 
}
```

So , my object newMember which I try to return is null at the end. So my question is, how can I return my object completed by AFN with this function? Many thanks

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://epnet.fr/"]` - ***Why?***

Comment: Fixed the indentation, always remember to add 4 spaces inside every block of code. Btw what do you mean for "failed code"? Describe the problem please.

Comment: Another victim of the tutsplus "tutorial", it seems.  That initial `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` is entirely pointless (and a leak under non-ARC code).

Answer (score 1):

What you are effectively asking is **"How do I make this asynchronous function synchronous?"**

The answer is that you don't. Or, you shouldn't.

What you should do is make that method return `(void)` (or `BOOL` + an `NSError**`) and then make whatever call is necessary to process the result of the query from your completion block.

---

There are a number of issues with that code.  The initial `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` is pointless given that the first thing you do in the completion block is `dicoNe = responseJSON;`.   There is no need to use `stringWithFormat:` with a static string in this expression: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://epnet.fr/"]`.

Calling `valueForKey:` on an array will return an array.   Something is afoul with the way you are handling that information (is `responseJSON` really an array?!).

Comment: Thanks for the issues. They are corrected. So, I can't return an Member object with this function ?

Comment: Exactly.

You either need to make the operation synchronous (**bad**) or make the block trigger the processing of the result (**good**).

Comment: @Benjamin - as an example, instead of calling `return newMember;`, you'd call something like `[myMemberList addMember:newMember];`